# Sorting matrix AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to sort matrix in AngularJS, I have tried this but it not working:

**script.js**

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.matrix = [
        [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [2, 2, 2]
    ];

function sort(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.matrix.lenght; i++){
    for (var j = 0; i < $scope.matrix.lenght - i; j++){
        if($scope.matrix[i][0] > $scope.matrix[j][0]){
        var temp = [];
        temp = $scope.matrix[i];
        $scope.matrix[i] = $scope.matrix[j];
        $scope.matrix[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And my .html file**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <ul ng-init="sort()">
           <li ng-repeat="line in matrix">
              {{line}}
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don`t understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very descriptive.  What are you expecting your code to do, and what is it actually doing?  Are you getting errors in your console?

Comment: Nothing happens, in my opinion this function sort isn`t calling

Comment: your `sort` function is not bounded to scope. Write it as `$scope.sort = function(){...}`, you can initialise it by calling `$scope.sort()` in your controller (without `ng-init`)

Comment: But what if I need to call it when I get my <ul>, how to call inside controller or what do you mean, Aleksey ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you want to sort the matrix rows by the first element in each row. Why not just use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

```js
let matrix = [
      [3, 3, 3],
      [4, 4, 4],
      [2, 2, 2]
    ];

console.log(matrix.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]));
```

Comment: But how to call this function correctly in my .html file?

Comment: You can store the sorted matrix in a separate variable in the controller (e.g. `$scope.sortedMatrix = $scope.matrix.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])`. And then in the html, reference this `sortedMatrix` like `ng-repeat="line in sortedMatrix"`.